# Dictionary and object to web service content type string

Tags: c#, web-services

I have Dictionary with values how to convert them to string of format  `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` simplest standard  way:

```
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"id", "1"},
        {"amount", "5"}
    };
```

The same question regarding class object with the same fields:

```
class values
{
    public String id  { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way is using json.NET library in order to post the data. you can convert your object to `application/json` like this:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
```

then post it to your service like this:

```
private static T Call<T>(string url, string body)
{
    var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Timeout = 60 * 1000;
    request.ContentLength = contentBytes.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";

    using (var requestWritter = request.GetRequestStream())
        requestWritter.Write(contentBytes, 0, (int)request.ContentLength);

    var responseString = string.Empty;
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you want to manually serialize your dictionary or object and then send it using a custom way or if you would like to automatically serialize and send them to a web service.

---

## The manual way:

#### Json

```
PM > Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Json.NET natively supports dictionary to Json object and, of course, object to json object serialization. You simply install it and than serialize using:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values); // values can be Dictionary<string, Anything> OR an object
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "amount", "5"
}
```

#### Form URL encoded

The cleanest way is to use the .NET built-in utility `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` (which also encodes any non-ASCII character):

```
var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("");
foreach(var item in values)
    nvc.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

var urlEncodedString = nvc.ToString();
```

Result:

```
id=1&amount=5
```

Please note that there is no direct way to serialize an object into a Form URL encoded string without adding its members manually, e.g.:

```
nvc.Add(nameof(values.id), values.id);
nvc.Add(nameof(values.amount), values.amount);
```

---

## The automatic way:

Everything is simpler if you just use `HttpClient`:

```
PM > Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
```

#### Json

You may need to also use `HttpClientExtensions` extension methods for automatic Json serialization (without it you need to serialize it manually as shown above):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    // set any header here
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://myurl", values); // values can be a dictionary or an object

    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyResultClass>();
}
```

#### Form URL encoded

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values)) // this must be a dictionary or a IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        content.Headers.Clear();
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyResultClass>();
    }
}
```

This way you may serialize dictionaries directly. Again for objects you need to convert them manually as shown above.